# generate classes from java test

Tags: java, class, testing

I wrote a java test and I run it from run as junit test 
in my project a bin folder was created with ".class" file
when I wrote a shell to launch the same test(with some modif) by command line it it launches the test without taking account my modif , do the tests use tha generated .class ?
could I remove this ".class" and launch test by command line ?
when I launch it by command line,do ".class" generated ? or should I add something to compile test?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your script you should add the proper call to `javac` (the Java compiler) in order to recompile your (source and test) classes, before invoking `java` (the Java runtime environment) to run your tests. The IDE does this automatically for you.

Provided your test classes are under the `test` directory, the command to compile your class would look something like this (you may need to add classpath too if you depend on external jars):

```
javac -sourcepath test *.java -d bin
```

Here is a reference about the [javac parameters on Linux/Solaris](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html), with examples.

Comment: I have already added this : -java () -classpath () path to project/bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package.classs

Comment: @lamisse `java` and `javac` are two different programs - see my update.

Comment: my problem is from Linux ,when I launch by command line after removing the generated .class , it says no calss found and I do not understand normally when I launch by command line it compile the test so generate .class associated to the test , non ?

Comment: so in my command line I should have -javac (path to java bin) -classpath() org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package.classs  ?

Comment: @lamisse on command line, after removing the .class files, you must call `javac` to compile your sources again before trying to run them with `java`. Otherwise you will get the aforementioned error.

Comment: @lamisse see my example and link

Comment: peter , javac -cp(all external jar) my_test.java -d  /generate_class

Comment: @lamisse Looks OK to me - does it do work in your environment?

Comment: yes it works but then, I should be careful when I work in windows or linux environement :
from eclipse(windows) tje class are generated automatically by eclipse when I compile the java test 
if I want to launch the same java test from linux ,I have to add javac before and remove the generated class ,no ?

Comment: @lamisse You may not need to remove the .class files completely (although you can, if you want to be on the safe side), but you should call `javac` in any case before running your tests. Eclipse is available on Linux too, btw - maybe it could solve your problem if you used the same IDE on all platforms?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the tests from IDE, your project (java source files) is most likely being automatically compiled before the run. If you want to run it from the command line, you need to compile the sources first using javac.